# How to make a cell where a specific date can be entered without editing date in the formula

Tags: microsoft-excel

I came up with this formula on excel and it does the job my job on telling me how many beans I made in a specific date range:
 `=SUMIFS(N10:N20,H10:H20,">=20/01/18",H10:H20,"<=02/02/18")`
But I don’t want to be editing the formula all the time as this isn’t convenient.

I tried removing the date from my formula, and typing in a cell for example `A4` to replace the date hoping the formula would recognise that in cell A4 there is a date.
But Excel didn’t detect that there is a date in cell A4.

So my question is: would it be possible to change the date through a cell, so that I don’t need to change the formula all the time. 
Thanks

~Neamus

Comment: As others have pointed out, you should be able to use a cell to contain the date. If it is not working, there must be an error in your formula, or you have entered the wrong data in the cells. We can't tell which it is because you haven't included that information in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Excel should be able to recognize the dates.

Put your `start` & end `dates` in `A4` & `A5`

Then try the below formula:

```
=SUMIFS(N10:N20,H10:H20,">="&A4,H10:H20,"<="&A5)
```

[image]

**Note.**

The `>` is still wrapped in double quotes, and then added using the ampersand to the CELL reference.
`">" & A4`

Answer (score 0):

Check the Screen Shots.

[image]

```
=SUMIFS(N10:N20,H10:H20,">=" & A4,H10:H20,"<=" & A5)
```

**NB:** I did nothing specific, but I guess the Date Value Cell Format of A4 
 & A5 doesn't matches the Range H10:H20.

*Hope this help you.*

Comment: Your answer gives a `#VALUE!` error.

Comment: @allquixotic ,, Never Possible,,, you have committed something wrong !!

Comment: He isn't wrong, your formula is incorrect, **as usual**.  You have used column N as the range for the second criteria range.  It should be column H, where the dates are.  Duh.  **HOPE THIS HELP YOU** and also **MAYBE YOU FIND CLUE FOR BETTER ANSWERING**

Comment: Yeah,, I got and corrected also. My Formula wasn't wrong,, otherwise how it  could produce CORRECT answer. Look the NB part I've had mentioned the correct Range H10:H20,,, actually I've tested on sheet in different Range and while after paste & edit here,,, it happens.